# Make a charcter mean an operator c++

Tags: c++, math, char, operators

I am trying to write a program that takes two numbers and allows the user to input either a, s, m, or d. Basically what I am trying to do is make the characters mean addition, subtraction, multiplication and division respectively. The problem is though is I am unsure of how to do it. Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double num1;
double num2;
char operation;

cout<<"Enter the first number: ";
cin>>num1;
cout<<"Enter the second number: ";
cin>>num2;
cout<<"What would you like to do with the numbers? a-addition, s=subtraction, m=multiplacation, d=division";
cin>>operation;
```

Comment: Simple [`switch` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) should do.

Comment: Use `if` or `switch` to decide what to do with the numbers based on the value of `operation`.

Comment: 1st year programming in C++ course question...

Comment: Note:  'a' is not equal to 'A', as they are two different letters and require two different comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a.aspx) statement:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double num1;
double num2;
char operation;

cout<<"Enter the first number: ";
cin>>num1;
cout<<"Enter the second number: ";
cin>>num2;
cout<<"What would you like to do with the numbers? a-addition, s=subtraction, m=multiplacation, d=division";
cin>>operation;

switch(operation)
{
    case 'a':
        ... // Addition code
        break;
    case 's':
        ... //Substraction code
        break;
    ...

}
```

You could also just use if and else, one for each type of operation.

Also, just as a tip, consider validating your input data (try typing more characters into your program, or invalid options).

Answer (score 2):

You use a switch:

```
switch (operation) {
  case 'a': // addition
    break;
  case 's': // subtraction
    break;
  // ...
  default: // none of these
    break;
}
```